# Testing functions with properties using Jest and Sinon

Tags: node.js, jestjs, sinon

am trying to write tests to test streams on my app, dealing with `fs` library with its `createWriteStream` function, so the stub i created is as follows:

```
writeStreamStub = sinon.stub()
onceStreamEventStub = sinon.stub()
endStreamStub = sinon.stub()
onStreamStub = sinon.stub()

createStreamStub = sinon.stub(fs, 'createWriteStream').returns({
  write: writeStreamStub,
  once: onceStreamEventStub,
  end: endStreamStub,
  on: onStreamStub
})
```

So now I can test for whether the functions are called and the returned functions are also called. But I am using the `--coverage` flag and the code of the callbacks of the returned functions is not covered, the `write` method is called inside a `process.nextTick` and I have no idea how to go about this. Is it possible to cover the whole code and the code inside the callbacks, and if so, how do I go about it. Thanks in advance.

**N.B. The variables are globaly declared**

Comment: It's unclear what your actual problem is, or what you refer to when saying "how to go about this". Please provide additional details.

Comment: @RomiHalasz What am trying to do, is test the code inside a callback function, e.g. when calling `stream.on('error', function () {})` now I want jest to go through the code inside the anonymous function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no cogent reason to use both sinon and jest, I'd recommend just using one library. If you decide to go with jest, here's a simple example. Assume you have a class like

```
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = class FileWriter {
  constructor() {
    this.writer = fs.createWriteStream('./testfile.txt');
  }

  writeFile() {
    process.nextTick(() => {
      this.writeContent('hello world');
    });
  }

  writeContent(content) {
    this.writer.write(content);
    this.writer.end();
  }

};
```

and in your unit-test you want to mock the behaviour of all the used fs-functions (createWriteStream, writer, end in this case) and just check if they are called with the correct arguments. You could do this with something like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const FileWriter = require('./FileWriter');
// use this to have mocks for all of fs' functions (you could use jest.fn() instead as well)
jest.mock('fs');
describe('FileWriter', () => {
  it('should write file with correct args', async () => {
    const writeStub = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(true);
    const endStub = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(true);
    const writeStreamStub = fs.createWriteStream.mockReturnValue({
      write: writeStub,
      end: endStub,
    });

    const fileWriter = new FileWriter();
    fileWriter.writeFile();
    await waitForNextTick();
    expect(writeStreamStub).toBeCalledWith('./testfile.txt');
    expect(writeStub).toBeCalledWith('hello world');
    expect(endStub).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});

function waitForNextTick() {
  return new Promise(resolve => process.nextTick(resolve));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is so much clearer, but given the fact that am calling `write` inside `process.nextTick`, will it wait for it to be called or do I have to do some extra steps for it to wait, and if so, what do I do to make it wait

Comment: I've edited the example - you have to indeed wait for the next tick to complete. There may be better ways to do this than I did with awaiting the promise, but it should work this way.